# rich PDF generation framework in java

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, freemarker

I have hundreds of rich PDFs that need to be generated from my application, they have images and colorful content. I was looking to build a framework which support a template and data model and can take care of rest, so adding anew pdfs would be just adding a new template. In the past i have used free-marker to generate HTML and that print HTML to PDFs, are there any better recent solution to solve this problem?

Comment: How is your question related to [tag:itext]?

Comment: iText is a software developer toolkit that allows users to integrate PDF functionalities within their applications, processes or products. Was curious if it has any extensions that support storing templates and configuration driven approach rather that programming.

Answer (score 1):

There are various things you could do:

- generate xml data, apply xslt transformation to style it, and convert
  the html document to a pdf
- code a small class that converts whatever data format you have to a pdf document (you would need to do all the layout through code)
- create a template (using whatever design program you want) pdf document, insert form fields, and have iText fill the form (several of our customers go for this approach)

Keep in mind that JasperReports uses a proprietary format. Whereas the approaches I suggested use only open and well-established formats.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).